# How do I include one angular template in another so that bootstrap classes still work?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which uses three different templates:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/pLrkya7r/4

These templates each have a panel and I want them to include a header template which is the same for each of them, like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="itemMenuTemplateUndefined">
    <div class = "panel panel-default" > 
        <div ng-include="'itemMenuTemplatePanelHeading'"></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div>Age: {{item.age}}</div>
        </div > 
    </div>
</script>
```

The included template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="itemMenuTemplatePanelHeading">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{item.firstName}} <b>{{item.lastName}}</b> (PROBLEM INCLUDED BUT NO COLOR)</div>
</script>
```

The problem is that although it includes the scope variable values and HTML, it doesn't seem to have the same HTML structure which causes e.g. the panel header color not to display.

**How can I get this example to work so that it has the same HTML structure as without ng-include so that Bootstrap continues to work?**

Comment: Do you mean, how you can have the template replace the `<div ng-include=...>` element instead of being appended as content?

Comment: No, I mean what charlietfl identified below, that `ng-include` puts in an extra div which causes Bootstrap to now render correctly.  How would I best get `ng-include` not to include that `div`, e.g. a `replace=true` of some kind perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the bootstrap css is very specific in targeting the panel heading as a direct child of the panel using selectors like `.panel-warning>.panel-heading`.

The extra `<div>` for the `ng-include` breaks this child relationship making it

```
<div class="panel">
    <div ng-include>
       <div class="panel-heading>
```

Some possible choices:

- Add appropriate classes to the `ng-include` div
- Copy the css rules and replace the `>` in selector with a space
- Use your own directive instead of ng-include and within the options
  set `replace:true`

Comment: Perfect, I solved it with your third suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/gxr49h96/3/

Comment: This is the replace I was suggesting, uses same template as the `ng-include`:  http://jsfiddle.net/gxr49h96/7/